# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in filename.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo, fatal-error

I have access to web root, folder with wordpress installation, and PHPMyAdmin ... Is there a way to fix this? I'm trying to implement prepared sql statements ...

Comment: It's either you have not enable the driver for your database or you have not install it or both .

Comment: Do you know how I could check?

Comment: Check with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: it says: PDO drivers no value

Comment: Is there a process to enable PDO driver?

Comment: That is OS dependant, in ubuntu simply installing the `php5-mysql` package will enable it. What is your OS ?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: You can refer to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)